# CMOS 4066 Question

Tags: noise, cmos

This is my first post here and I have a question about a CMOS circuit I have been designing for I while using the 4066 (I'm a noob to digital electronics). I am using a 4066 to pass random pulses I generated by feeding a noise generator with two two outputs (the generator is connected to a JFET amp and then clamped with diodes to two different dc voltages) into a 4050 (one buffer for each noise gen output). The pulses work perfectly. The only problem is, when the 4066 is not enabled, about 1 volt of the pulses pass through each switch. I was wondering if there was any way to fix that! Here is my circuit:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: connect 1k resistor at the output terminal of cd4066 and ground

Comment: Thanks!! It worked perfectly! I will write that technique down for the future!

Comment: Use the spare bilateral switch to short the output to ground. This requires an inverted control line of course.

Comment: @Yogece As per Yogece's suggestion I modified my circuit and the following:
[look here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50290962/random_pulse_2_28_14_2.png)

I added the two extra buffers on the bottom as the amplitude of the output directly from the 4066 (after I added the 2 1K resistors) was a little too low for me. Did I do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: @ZackElec i couldn't see your modified circuit

Answer (score 1):

You need to put low-impedance loads on the outputs in order to minimize the effect of DC (resistive) and AC (capacitive) leakage through the 4066.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, adding a resistor to the desired "idle state" voltage will cause the output to swing to that voltage when the 4066 is disabled.  If one would like the output to stay at its present voltage when the 4066 is disabled, and if one is driving a high-impedance load, one may instead use a capacitor.  If a capacitor is used, then while the 4066 is enabled the cap voltage will swing toward the input, and when it is disabled it will tend to stay more or less where it is (though it will likely drift away from its present voltage at some speed).  The larger the cap, the more slowly the cap will switch to the desired voltage, but the more slowly it will drift away.  Feeding the output of the 4066 into an op amp wired as a voltage follower may also slow down the drift.

I'm not sure exactly what you are intending your circuit for, but some kinds of "random computer noise" were historically generated by feeding a noise source through an analog switch which was turned on briefly about 5-10 times/second, and then a cap; the voltage on that cap was then used to control the frequency of an oscillator.

Comment: I am using this circuit for fun (I'm just a hobbiest!) in a random number generator circuit! I know I could have easily used something much simpler, however I wanted to put my circuit design skills to the test because in the past, when I have designed larger and complicated circuits, they did not even come close to working! Thanks for the explanation! It was very clear!